# SwiftUI - Text working, TextField gives error

Tags: swiftui

This works:

```
ForEach(toDoItems) {toDoItem in
    Text(toDoItem.title)
}
```

This gives "Value of type 'NSManagedObject' has no member 'title'":

```
ForEach(toDoItems) {toDoItem in
    TextField("", text: toDoItem.title)
}
```

Not sure why it no longer works.  The data is coming from core data.

Comment: I think you should add the model for the `toDoItem`

Comment: What is `toDoItems`?

Comment: It's a core data model.  Let's just say it has toDoItem.title and toDoItem.id

Comment: The text argument should be something `bindable`

Comment: Can you give an example please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Text takes a `String` into its initializer, because it only displays it and cannot mutate it. Whatever goes into Text is read-only.
`TextField` takes a Binding, because it mutates the value. The binding connects the TextField and the parent view so it knows about any changes to the input.

e.g.:

```
struct ContentView: View {

    let title: String = "This is a string"
    @State var inputString: String = ""

    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            Text(title)
            TextField("Here goes a binding",
                      text: $inputString)
        }
    }
}
```